# Can I forward declare a lambda so that code above it can call it?

Tags: c++, lambda, forward-declaration

I was wondering if something like this is possible. I also tried by declaring a class and constructor above, and then below just constructing an object and having the constructor run all the lines. It doesn't accept the constructor definition in the function, i.e., `myclass::myclass() { /*definition*/}`

```
void present();
// I was hoping this would let the below code know of the lambda.

if (GFX::bFPSLimitOn) {
    if (frameLatency > 1.0 / GFX::FPSLimit) present();
    else return;
} else present();

auto present = [&]() {
    GFX::clearScreen();
    GFX::renderScene(activeCamera);
    GUI::renderGUI();
    GFX::presentScreen();
    lastFramePresentTimestamp = currentTime;
};
```

Comment: no. A lambda has an "unutterable type" and is not constructible. You must define it where you declare it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this, as opposed to just defining & forward-declaring a normal function?

Comment: You can use `std::function` for this purpose.

Comment: @Scott Hunter This is a function called renderAndPresent, I kind of wanted it contained all in here. Also, I can just put the lambda above it. Or make a separate function, I just thought it would be cleaner this way.

Comment: Though a lambda is sometimes useful for such things, this case can be solves much more nicely by simply refactoring the if. If FpsLimitOn && framelatency < 1 return. Then you can just write the code from the lambda inline.

Comment: If you don't need capture, a lambda can be converted to a function pointer. note that you only need to capture locals, globals are accessible without capture.

Comment: But if you do use a capture, the captured context will be that of the definition. And that gets you into a chicken-and-egg situation here. You capture the context _after_ the if-statement, but that context doesn't exist yet inside the if statement. So what would the captured context be? The problem isn't C++, the problem is circular logic.

Comment: Imagining for a moment you can declare a lambda, you won't be able to call it before it is constructed anyway, so the whole exercise is dubious.

Comment: @n.m. Oh so you're saying it wouldn't work anyway. If it didn't capture anything it would , but if it uses a captured variable it wouldn't work?

Comment: Even if it didn't capture, a lambda is an object you need to construct and only then use. `auto present = [&]() ...` is an *object construction*. It needs to be *performed*.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't forward declare a lambda.  When you make a lambda you get some compiler generated named class type.  You don't know what that name will be so you can't forward declare it.

If you need to have it forward declared then most likely you'll need to write a functor instead as you will know the name.